# Find input control in dynamically added div

Tags: asp.net

Upon dynamically adding a Table webcontrol from the code-behind of my aspx page, I then use

```
    TableCell tableCell = tableRow.Cells[1];
    foreach (Control ctrc in tableCell.Controls)
    {
     ...
    }
```

to find the objects I am interest in.

I would rather use a div with a span tag, instead of the table, and use something similar to

```
   foreach (Control ctrc in span.Controls)
   {
    ...
   }
```

As my div also has a label, how do I specify that I am only interested in the objects contained within the span tag?

Comment: So you have something like `<div runat="server"><label runat="server" ><span runat="server"><span runat="server"></div>`?

Comment: I did not need the runat="server" attribute. `<div id="1"><label for="lbl1" id="lbl1"></label><span class="controls"><input name="ctl00$PageContent$txt1" type="text" id="txt1"/></span></div>`

Comment: Then that's a problem. Just a plain `span` will never come up in server side control collection, because it is not a server-side control. `runat="server"` is what makes it one

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to filter the list by a type:

```
span.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
```

I know TextBox controls are not what you are looking for, but I'm not sure what specifically you need, so replace TextBox with whatever... (HtmlGenericControl?).  You can also use LINQ Where, which is nice:

```
span.Controls.Where(i => [SOME CONDITION]);
```

And the list is filtered to whatever you want.  Since you are using HTML elements with `runat="server"`, you have to know what the HTML control type is, which I am not 100% sure what the class names are since I don't use them that often.

Comment: I'm working off a List, and trying `span.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` results in the error: `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'method group' because 'method group' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`